# Passing values from jquery.ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, soap

I have created a script that sends post data to php via the $.ajax method

```
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$compid = $_POST['compid'];

$queryData = array(
                    "Username"=>$uname,
                    "Password"=>$pass,
                    "CompanyID"=>$compid
       );

$result = $client->GetUserStores($queryData);
```

The post data is used to fill an array used to make a validation through a web service. I keep getting an error that System.FormatException Input was not in a correct format. But when i make a test php script that does this:

```
$uname = "user";
$pass = "password";
$compid = "99";

$queryData = array(
                    "Username"=>$uname,
                    "Password"=>$pass,
                    "CompanyID"=>$compid
       );

$result = $client->GetUserStores($queryData);
```

I get the data returned as expected and I am able to parse the xml response needed. Doesnt type juggling in PHP handle the number as string or integer if need be when it is placed into the array?

Here is my ajax call in case that may be of any help:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'login.php',
      data:     {uname:storage.readValue('uname'),pass:storage.readValue('pass'),compid:storage.readValue('companyID')},
      success: function(data) {
        alert("success" + data);
      }
    });
```

Any help at all to see where I am going wrong here will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: if you ask for POST the type of $.ajax should be POST not GET

Comment: `type: "GET",` != `$_POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your GET method to post:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'login.php',
      data:     {uname:storage.readValue('uname'),pass:storage.readValue('pass'),compid:storage.readValue('companyID')},
      success: function(data) {
        alert("success" + data);
      }
    });
```